# App screen layout not working in landscape orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The following code is working properly in portrait orientation, but in landscape orientation, the image is covering the whole screen and none of the other views are showing. which part of the code I have to replace to solve the issue?

Screenshots here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogMnE.jpg "portrait view"
                 https://i.stack.imgur.com/itr1y.jpg "landscape view"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resturant_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/resturant"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resturant_name"
    android:layout_below="@id/resturant_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Etarnity Resturant"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resturant_description"
    android:layout_below="@id/resturant_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="Best food quality in cheapest price.One of the best stores of california. Home delivery available 24x7"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post screenshot for better understating.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` to your layout like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/resturant_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/resturant"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resturant_name"
                android:layout_below="@id/resturant_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Etarnity Resturant"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resturant_description"
                android:layout_below="@id/resturant_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:text="Best food quality in cheapest price.One of the best stores of california. Home delivery available 24x7"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There Are two ways to solve this problem

**First**

create different layout for landscape view and inflate at runtime orientation change

**Second**

For big size layout we have used `ScrollView` Or `NestedScrollView`.Some time Layout need more space So in this situation we have used **ScrollView**

**See Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/resturant_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/house1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resturant_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/resturant_image"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Etarnity Resturant"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resturant_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/resturant_name"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Best food quality in cheapest price.One of the best stores 
           of california. Home delivery available 24x7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In this code i am using nestedscroll view to scroll layout

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by two methods.

1.Create a layout for landscape orientation and change the layout in landscape and portrait orientation

2.Change the image width from match_parent to a fixed size and put it in a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn your device to landscape mode following line

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

starts its job. Which in turn forces your ImageView to increase its bounds to preserve aspect ratio of the image/drawable and your image goes out of the available view.

Read more about ImageViews [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView)

Try removing above line and see how your app performs in both orientations.
OR
Use ScrollView with current code.

I would prefer scrollView if nothing works.